# how to ignore the last unknow characters at the end of the json string

Tags: iphone

{

education =     (

```
        {
    school =             {
        id = 108102169223234;
        name = psss;
    };
    type = College;
    year =             {
        id = 142833822398097;
        name = 2010;
    };
}
```

);

}
!-- 1.2398s -->

the above  leads me error as " NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character"

Answer (score 1):

not even close to valid JSON.. http://www.jsonlint.com/
Are you in charge of generating the feed? If so I would think it a lot better to fix the problem at the source than try re-factor your code to accommodate what ever that is that is getting returned.
Are you using a JSON framework in Xcode to parse that string?

Comment: Then that is for sure why it is failing. that is no where near valid JSON. That almost looks like a output from a NSDictionary if i recall.